# Using CName to point to the Availability Group listener

Tags: availability-groups

I have SQL Server 2008 named "OldSQLServer". Its data is accessed by hundred of SQL Servers via linked server.

I am moving the "OldSQLServer" to AG on SQL Server 2019, windows 2019. And I want to keep connecting to it by “OldSQLServer” name.

So I created windows cluster “MyCluster” and AG group “MyAGGroup” with AG Listener “MyAGListener”. I pointed virtual computer name “oldSQLServer” to the same IP address as “MyAGListener”

Everything looks to be working. Clients connect to “OldSQLServer, they connect to “MyAGListener” IP, which takes them to the primary node, be it “MyNode1” or “MyNode2”.

I wonder if there could be any issues with such setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder if there could be any issues with such setup?

There are some additional configuration steps required to make Windows Integrated Auth and TLS work when connecting via a DNS alias.

For the Windows Auth steps see: [How to Add a Hostname Alias for a SQL Server Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dbrowne/how-to-add-a-hostname-alias-for-a-sql-server-instance)

For the Certificate configuration, it's the same as enabling connectivity via the AG Listener, documented here: [Listeners & TLS/SSL certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/listeners-client-connectivity-application-failover?view=sql-server-ver15#SSLcertificates)

And note that you can alternatively just use the name for your AG Listener.